# Looking for iOS 15.8 support files for XCode14.2(14C18)

Tags: ios, swift

my Xcode Version in laptop is 14.2 (14C18) and the ios version of my phone is 15.8
i try to put 15.8 device support file but there is no any file for 15.8
can anyone help me to download iOS device support file for iOS version - 15.8 ?

Comment: can you solve that? I am in the same sad situation that I would desperately need the 15.8 support files

Comment: it's not duplicated. there is not support for 15.8

Comment: use image 15.5. Rename the folder from 15.5 -> 15.8

Comment: @ParthKanpara Did you get the 15.8 support file?

Comment: @Muju no i didn't get till now

Comment: I tried @AAryan 's suggestion and it worked for me! Cheers mate!

Comment: I can build app into ios15.7.1 device with Xcode 14.2 but cannot build the app to ios15.8. I think you can build to simulator with ios16.2 or use a 15.7.1 or earlier device.

Comment: @AAryan 's suggestion working. Tested in xcode 14.2 (14C18), ios version 15.8 (19H370)